# Drag items to canvas from menu in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I was trying to do a simple application that, from a menu where you have simple geometric figures, you could drag those figures to a canvas (i suppose it has to be a canvas) and those figures appeared on said canvas.
I realized that I have no idea how to begin and I'm having trouble searching for solutions. I could further explain what i want to do if it is needed. Thank you in advance.